# Timestamp not getting updated

Tags: linux, shell-script

I've written a piece of code but time stamp is not getting updated. It displays the time when the script runs and keep on displaying the same time even when loop is running and time is getting changed.

```
T=$(date)
while [ -f $BACKUP_FILE ]
do
    echo "[$T] Backup is in Progress" | tee -a $LOG_FILE
    sleep 10
done
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: you can use `echo "backup is in progress  | sed -e "s/^/$(date) : /"` in while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `T=$(date)` inside your `do`..`while` loop or it never gets updated (i.e. as it stands the date is ascertained only once at the top of your code).

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the date once to a variable outside the loop body, and dereferencing that variable inside the loop. The value in the variable is never updated, so for the duration of the loop, it will only ever contain the value initially assigned at line 1.

In order to get the effect you seem to want, do away with the variable completely and just call `date` inside the loop body:

```
while [ -f "$BACKUP_FILE" ]
do
    echo "[$(date)] Backup is in Progress" | tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
    sleep 10
done
```